# Checking individual fields for changes in an EntityState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

In our database we have a user. A user can have certain metadata (Like their location, age, etc) associated with them. In addition to that they have a profile image.
A user can edit any of these things at any time.

[image]

The problem we run into is that when a user goes to edit their information, but they don't choose an image -- the previous image gets erased (Null).

I figure that when we go to save the modified user, we should be able to say `if(user.profileImage == null) don't save it`

I figure that would come into play in our user repository which uses the following code:

```
public void SaveUser(Domain.Entities.User user)
        {
            if (user.UserId == 0)
            {
                context.Users.Add(user);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                //The logic would be here
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

However I seems that no matter what we try it doesn't work.

So my question is: Is there a way to check changes to individual fields instead of the entire EntityState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing image data in the Session and then if the image upload was null I simply inserted the session attribute into my image, effectively keeping the old image if left empty.

`Session["image"] = productService.GetProduct(id).Image;`

Then in the post I said...

```
if (image != null)
                {
                    product.ImageType = image.ContentType;
                    product.Image = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                    image.InputStream.Read(product.Image, 0, image.ContentLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    product.Image = (byte[])Session["image"];
                }
```

Comment: Not a good workaround to be honest. You will have users wondering why their image disappeared just because they were going to have some food before they clicked the submit button. I have posted an alternative in my answer, it uses basically the database as storage where the image is already in instead of the fragile session object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way:

```
context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Location).IsModified = true;
context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Age).IsModified = true;
// etc.
```

Be aware that you cannot set `IsModified` to `false` once the property is marked as modified. So, something like this ...

```
context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Image).IsModified = false;
```

... **does not work**.

**Edit** Alternative solution:

```
public void SaveUser(Domain.Entities.User user)
{
    if (user.UserId == 0)
    {
        context.Users.Add(user);
    }
    else
    {
        var userInDb = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == user.UserId);

        if (user.profileImage == null)
            user.profileImage = userInDb.profileImage;

        context.Entry(userInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This keeps the value of `profileImage` as it is in the database if the user didn't post a new image (= `user.profileImage == null`), otherwise it saves the new image.

Comment: So how would you explicitly say "if this field doesn't have anything in it, don't update it?"

Comment: @Johannes: I don't know any other way than the obvious: `If (user.Image != null && user.Image.Length > 0) context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Image).IsModified = true;` I don't think that EF has any option to make that happen automatically. After all, for EF, "nothing in it" is a valid value which it will write an UPDATE for like for any other value.